# Get Custom Post Child Term

Tags: terms

I am trying to echo the custom post's child "section", if one exists. I only want to show the second level, or child, sections. This is working, however, it displays the 1st level section if no second level exists.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'section' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
    $term_slugs_arr = array(
    );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_slugs_arr[0] = $term->name;
    }
    $terms_slug_str = join( " ", $term_slugs_arr);

endif;

echo '<p class="sub-section">'.$terms_slug_str.'</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be help you.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'section' );

echo '<ul>'; 
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
           $term_slugs_arr[0] = $term->name;
           $termchildren = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'section' );
           foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
                  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                  echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**OR**

Check [this Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)